# What's the OST that plays in the last episode of season 3?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

I want to know what's the OST that plays at the 12:56 minute mark when Mirio starts explaining his quirk.

[image: Episode Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

## Momo Yaoyorozu

From Disc 2 of the Season 3 OST. You can hear it on YouTube [here](https://youtu.be/Z_D1Os1ZGws?t=1h41m22s).